# ¿Como mostrar registros según rango de fecha?

Tags: php, mysql

Saludos de nuevo, se me ha presentado esta inquietud, quiero mostrar en una tabla los cursos dictados del día.

Los cursos que están siendo dictados los guardo con una fecha de inicio y una fecha final, estoy pensando en si puedo seleccionar de esos cursos los que estén siendo dictados hoy. Por ejemplo:

Curso PHP
Fecha inicio: 20-08-2017
Fecha Final: 20-08-2017

Esta es la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que busque entre esos los rangos de fecha inicio y fin para asi ver si la fecha actual esta entre ese rango, y así mostrarlo como curso del día. No se si hay una manera de hacer eso. Gracias

Este es el código que estoy usando pero no me arroja nada:

```
<?php
$fechadesde = date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('d'), date('m'), 
date('Y')));
$fechahasta = date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('d') + 1, date('m'), 
date('Y')));

$query= "SELECT curso,inicio,final,horario FROM cursos WHERE inicio >= 
'".$fechadesde."' AND final < '".$fechahasta."' ";
$sql = $mysqli->query($query);
while($row = $sql-> fetch_assoc()){
 ?>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><a href=""><?php echo $row['curso'] ?></a></td>
    <td><a href=""><?php echo $row['inicio'] ?></a></td>
    <td><a href=""><?php echo $row['final'] ?></a></td>
    <td><a href=""><?php echo $row['horario'] ?></a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 <?php } echo mysqli_error($mysqli); ?>
 </table>
```

Comment: Si hay manera de hacer esto, pero si no indicas mínimamente la estructura de las tablas es difícil de brindarte una respuesta y me temo que eventualmente tu pregunta podrá terminar siendo cerrada. A nivel más conceptual podrías leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos/92772#92772) que trata una situación similar a la que planteas.

Comment: He puesto la estructura de mi tabla Patricio. Checa a ver si puedes ayudarme! Gracias

Comment: `inicio`y `fin` son campos texto, el formato de la fecha es el que muestras en el ejemplo? es decir: `dd-mm-yyy`?

Comment: Exacto Patricio, estan en este formato dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: He colocado el codigo patricio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que esto debiera resolver tu pregunta:

```
set @hoy = CURDATE();

select *
       from cursos_abiertos
       where STR_TO_DATE(inicio, '%d-%m-%Y')<= @hoy
             and STR_TO_DATE(fin, '%d-%m-%Y')>= @hoy;
```

El uso de la variable `@hoy` es simplemente para estar seguro que el valor en las dos comparaciones sea el mismo, pero eventualmente podrías utilizar `BETWEEN` para hacer más compacto el código:

```
select *
       from cursos_abiertos
       where CURDATE() between STR_TO_DATE(inicio, '%d-%m-%Y') and STR_TO_DATE(fin, '%d-%m-%Y');
```

Comment: Tal cual Patricio, me ha funcionado. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar mktime:

```
$fechadesde = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), 1, date('Y')));
$fechahasta = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') + 1, 1, date('Y')));
```

Asi te aparecerian todos los cursos que hay en el mes, si lo necesitas de cada dia puedes probar cambiando el `('m')` por `('d')`

Comment: y esas variables tendria que colocarlas en el WHERE?

Comment: Si tu sentencia seria algo como $sql = "select * from cursos where fecha_inicio >= ' ". $fechadesde ." ' and fecha_final < ' ". $fechahasta ." ' ";

Comment: Edwin, el formato de la fecha tiene que ser 'Y-m-d'?? pregunto eso porque estoy guardando las fechas 'd-m-Y'.. si lo coloco asi antes del mktime no habra problema?

Comment: El formato es el que mejor te convenga, no hay problema si lo cambias

Comment: Lo he hecho como me has dicho pero me da este error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\SA\admin\today_courses.php:130 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: puedes poner el codigo que usas para ayudarte un poco mejor

Comment: Hermano el error se encuentra en la consulta sql, por lo que pude probar tienes escrito (final) en la consulta y tienes (fin) en tu base de datos

Comment: Edwin he arreglado mi consulta. Disculpa mi vista esta fallando, ahora lo que me muestra es la tabla vacia, y en efecto tengo un registro de un curso con fecha de inicio de hoy, pero aun asi no me muestra nada.

Comment: Edwin he hecho un var_dump a la variable de la consulta y fijate en esto: string(105) "SELECT curso,inicio,fin,horario FROM cursos_abiertos WHERE inicio >= '01-06-2019' AND fin < '01-07-2019' " mira las fechas de las variables $fechadesde y $fechahasta, porque esta pasando eso

Comment: Ok el problema esta en la declaracion del mktime, cambialos por estos date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'))) ---- date('d-m-Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 1, date('Y')))

Comment: Perfecto ahora si, edwin. Por ultimo me puedes explicar los parametros despues del mktime por favor

Comment: Me alegro que ya funcione, para que entiendas mejor los parametros del mktime es mejor que consultes el manual oficial de php sobre este (http://php.net/manual/es/function.mktime.php)

Comment: Ok esta bien. gracias edwin, y disculpa es primera vez que me toca hacer algo asi.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar la siguiente sentencia:

```
Select curso, descripcion from Cursos where cursoId = 1
             and Date between '2016/02/25' and '2017/02/27'
```