# Consulta errónea MySQL Fechas

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Dispongo de una base de datos con una tabla llamada "reservas".

Quiero que me extraiga las reservas que están ocupadas durante el periódo que se solicita, contando el día de entrada (check_in) como el día de salida (check_out).

```
CREATE TABLE RESERVAS (
    idreserva INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    idcabana INT NOT NULL,
    idemail VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    check_in DATE NOT NULL,
    check_out DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (idcabana) REFERENCES CABANAS(idcabana),
    FOREIGN KEY (idemail) REFERENCES CLIENTES(idemail)
);

INSERT INTO RESERVAS (idreserva, idcabana, idemail, check_in, check_out) VALUES 
(1, 1, "d@hotmail.com", "2017/03/15", "2017/03/18"), 
(2, 1, "c@hotmail.com", "2017/03/20", "2017/03/22"),
(3, 2, "c333@hotmail.com", "2017/04/05", "2017/04/18"), 
(4, 2, "sar@hotmail.com", "2017/06/23", "2017/06/25"), 
(5, 3, "de@hotmail.com", "2017/06/07", "2017/06/18"), 
(6, 3, "daasda@hotmail.com", "2017/08/16", "2017/08/30");
```

Por ejemplo: si insertamos dos fechas (2017/03/17 --- 2017/03/19) nos debe mostrar todas las reservas menos la primera, debido a que 2017/03/17 está en el período del primer "idreserva".

**Consulta propuesta y errónea:**

```
SELECT idreserva FROM reservas 
where (check_in>='2017/03/17' OR check_in<='2017/03/17') AND (check_out>='2017/03/19' OR check_out<='2017/03/19');
```

¿Cuál sería la solución?

Comment: Ese no es el formato que tienen los campos DATE en MySQL, de ahí el problema, el formato sería YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: aparte del error del formato, cual es el error que te sale???

Comment: puedes mostrar una imagen de tu base de datos??

Comment: El error que me sale es que siempre me da las mismas "idreservas", ponga una fecha fuera del plazo de reserva o no... Siempre me da TODAS las reservas.

Comment: Si he subido la imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de realizar la consulta con la tabla e información que suministraste lo único que tuve que realizar fue cambiar los (/) por (-) tanto en el `INSERT` como en la consulta.

```
SELECT idreserva FROM reservas 
where (check_in>='2017-03-17' OR check_in<='2017-03-17') AND (check_out>='2017-03-19' OR check_out<='2017-03-19');
```

De igual manera si puedes proporcionarnos el código error que te da, mucho mejor, así puedo refinar mi respuesta.

En la consulta de inserción de datos tiene que estar de esta manera:

```
INSERT INTO RESERVAS (idreserva, idcabana, idemail, check_in, check_out) VALUES 
(1, 1, "d@hotmail.com", "2017-03-15", "2017-03-18"), 
(2, 1, "c@hotmail.com", "2017-03-20", "2017-03-22"),
(3, 2, "c333@hotmail.com", "2017-04-05", "2017-04-18"), 
(4, 2, "sar@hotmail.com", "2017-06-23", "2017-06-25"), 
(5, 3, "de@hotmail.com", "2017-06-07", "2017-06-18"), 
(6, 3, "daasda@hotmail.com", "2017-08-16", "2017-08-30");
```

> MySql type DATE tiene la estructura YYYY-MM-DD.

Evidencia:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

El problemas está en la lógica del filtro, lo que debieras hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT idreserva 
    FROM reservas 
    WHERE '2017/03/19' >= check_in
    AND '2017/03/17' <= check_out
```

Es decir, de todas las reservas traer solo aquellas dónde se dan dos condiciones:

- Que la fecha hasta sea igual o posterior a la del checkin
- Que la fecha desde sea menor o igual a la del checkout

Esto está mejor explicado en [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos) pregunta

Comment: Esa consulta no es del todo correcta, debido a que si inserto fechas que ESTÁN LIBRES LAS CABAÑAS y sí se puede reservar, me sale siempre el idreserva=1. Por ejemplo, pongamos estas fechas: '2017/03/24' 
y '2017/03/27'

Comment: Si intentas con esas fechas la consulta no debería devolverte registros, por que efectivamente según el ejemplo que diste no hay registros, tu pregunta dice: "Quiero que me extraiga las reservas que están ocupadas durante el periódo que se solicita, contando el día de entrada (check_in) como el día de salida (check_out).", revisa esto por que me da la impresión que estas esperando algo que no está del todo claro en tu pregunta, al menos para mí.

Comment: Con esas fechas sí devuelve resultados, ahí está el problema, devuelve "idreserva = 1". SELECT idreserva FROM reservas WHERE '2017/03/24' >= check_in AND '2017/03/27' <= check_out

Comment: La fecha de reserva del id=1 es del 15/3 al 18/3 no hay forma que 2017/03/27 sea menor o igual a 2017/03/18. Revisa este fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18f16/13

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien. Imagínate que está reservada una cabaña del dia 2 al día 4 de X mes, y un cliente quiere reservar esa cabaña del día 3 al día 8, obviamente no sería permitido. ¡Eso quiero realizar! Con que uno de los dos días esté dentro del rango (día entrada, día salida) debe fallar. Osease creo que haría que realizarse 4 comprobaciones, ¿es así?.

Comment: La consulta que te pasé justamente lo que te dice son las reservas existentes que se "cruzarían" con la nueva. No necesitas hacer las 4 comprobaciones que mencionas. Verifica esta pregunta que tiene un poco más de teoría: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos

Answer (score 0):

A ver si entendí, querés los idreserva que no estén entre las fechas indicadas, sería algo así?

```
SELECT idreserva FROM RESERVAS WHERE not ('2017/03/19' >= check_in AND '2017/03/17' <= check_out);
```