# Verificar que días hay en un rango de fechas

Tags: php, mysql, date

Estoy haciendo un sistema de citas medicas, y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo un formulario donde se especifica el rango de fechas de atención del doctor y especialidad, otro rango de tiempo durante el día, y 7 checkbox indicando cada día de la semana

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
    <input type="date" name="startdate"><br>
    <label>Fecha Inicio</label>
    <input type="date" name="enddate"><br>
    <label>Hora Inicio</label>
    <input type="time" name="starttime"><br>
    <label>Hora Final</label>
    <input type="time" name="endtime"><br>
    <input type="checkbox">Lunes
    <input type="checkbox">Martes
    <input type="checkbox">Miercoles
    <input type="checkbox">Jueves
    <input type="checkbox">Viernes
    <input type="checkbox">Sabado
    <input type="checkbox">Domingo<br>
    <button type="submit">enviar</button><br><br>
</form>
```

Y con este código recorro el rango de fechas, el rango de tiempo cada 30 minutos,

```
<?php
$StartTime= $_POST["starttime"];
$EndTime = $_POST["endtime"];

function get_minutes ( $start, $end ) {
   while ( strtotime($start) <= strtotime($end) ) {
       $minutes[] = date("h:i A", strtotime( "$start" ) );  
       $start = date("h:i A", strtotime( "$start + 30 mins")) ;      
   }
   return $minutes;  
}

$minutes = get_minutes($StartTime, $EndTime);  
foreach($minutes as $minute) {  
    echo $minute .'<br />';  
}

$begin = new DateTime( $_POST["startdate"] );
$end   = new DateTime( $_POST["enddate"] );

$diasdisponibles = [];
for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+1 day')){
    echo $i->format("Y-m-d")."<br>";
}
?>
```

Pero necesito que verifique si el rango de fecha cae entre los **días** de los checkbox seleccionados para poder insertarlos en la base de datos:
Estas serian mis tablas **programaciondoctor**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver el registro tiene como fecha el 13 de diciembre hasta el 18, eso seria desde un miércoles hasta el día lunes de la siguiente semana, pero en las columnas de los días de la semana los únicos días activos son, el día jueves y domingo, osea dos días laborales. Mientras el registro se hace, al mismo tiempo otra tabla es afectada **ticketscita**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde registro las fechas de los dos días laborales del rango especificado, y las horas de atención del rango de tiempo ingresado ( cada 30 min) con su respectivo estado.

Y no se como podría hacer que me filtre esas fechas donde caen jueves y domingo. ¿Alguna sugerencia? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como verificar si dos intervalos de datos tienen elementos compartidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la función DATE_FORMAT de SQL para obtener el dia de la semana y ya con esto puedes hacer tu consulta
Aclarar que el valor devuelto por la misma función es un entero entre 0 y 6 donde 0 corresponde al Domingo y así sucesivamente hasta el Sábado

```
SELECT * FROM TICKETSCITA WHERE DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%w") IN (0,4)
```

Con esto podrias filtrar por aquellas citas que cayeran Jueves o Domingo, si quieres otros dias en específico puedes variar los números del IN