# Mostrar todas las habitaciones, y saber si esta libre u ocupada, de acuerdo a una fecha especifica

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

[image: diagrama BD]

De acuerdo a una fecha especifica, mostrar todas las habitaciones, ademas mostrar si esta libre o no (eso se puede saber con la reserva).

Hasta ahora he conseguido ubicar las habitaciones reservadas:

```
SELECT  h.habitacion_numero as habitacion,
    r.inicio_fecha as fecha_inicio,
    r.fin_fecha as fecha_fin 
    FROM habitaciones h 
    inner join reservas r 
        on h.habitacion_numero=r.habitacion
```

Comment: Qué llevas hasta ahora?  debes mostrar un avance  especificar en que estás atorado

Comment: **Lo unico que avance, es mostrar las habitaciones reservadas  **    
`SELECT h.habitacion_numero as habitacion,
       r.inicio_fecha as fecha_inicio,
       r.fin_fecha as fecha_fin                                                             FROM habitaciones h
 inner join reservas r on h.habitacion_numero=r.habitacion";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obtener el estado de una habitación a una determinada fecha es bastante sencillo, tu consulta efectivamente te da las habitaciones reservadas y sus fechas, lo que deberías hacer es refinar esta consulta para que aplique solo a una fecha y las habitaciones que están en la misma, serán las que están reservadas y las que no, las que están disponibles.

```
set @fecha = STR_TO_DATE('2017/12/09','%Y/%m/%d');

SELECT  h.habitacion_numero,
        CASE WHEN hr.habitacion_numero is null 
              THEN 'Disponible'
              ELSE 'Reservada'
        END  AS 'Estado'      
        FROM habitaciones h
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT   h1.habitacion_numero
                            FROM habitaciones h1
                            inner join reservas r 
                                on h1.habitacion_numero=r.habitacion
                            WHERE @fecha BETWEEN r.inicio_fecha AND r.fin_fecha
          ) hr
          on hr.habitacion_numero = h.habitacion_numero;
```

Explicación:

- En primer lugar configuro una variable `@fecha` con la fecha que voy a consultar
- Tu consulta la he parametrizado para que filtre únicamente las habitaciones donde `@fecha` entra dentro del rango de cada reserva, con esto obtengo las "Resevadas"
- La consulta principal es sobre `habitaciones` con un `LEFT` sobre las "Reservadas", si se encuentra obviamente es una habitación "Reservada" sino se trata de una disponible.

Puedes probarlo mediante este [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631a8/13/1)

Comment: Gracias totales @Patricio Morano!!!

Comment: una consulta, como haria para filtrar las habitaciones disponibles con un rango de dos fechas. Osea dos valores de fecha ingresados compararlo con las fechas de; fecha_inicio , fecha_fin  y mostrar las disponibles - avance con eso  [enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631a8/20).

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos) responde tu comentario. Puedes verificar también esta [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631a8/28/2)