# ORACLE Procedimiento Almacenado para evitar registros de fechas incluidas en un rango de fechas

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Mi tabla de Training es esta:

```
CREATE TABLE training(
    id_training      NUMBER,
    id_user          NUMBER,
    start_training   DATE,
    end_training     DATE
 );
```

El problema que surge es cuando tengo un usuario (cualquier usuario) con fecha de

> 01-01-18 en "start_training" y 05-01-18 en "end_training"

Ahora si quiero registrar fechas con el mismo usuario, pero esta vez con

> 03-01-18 como "start_training" y 06-01-18 en "end_training"

Estas fechas son diferentes a las fechas del primer registro, pero 03-01-18 está incluido en la rango de fechas del primer registro, es viable crear un trigger para evitar que me haga un insert o me estoy complicando más de lo que creo? De antemano, gracias.

PROCEDURE:

```
create or replace procedure "training_pc"(
pc_id_training training.id_training%type,
pc_id_user training.id_user%type,
pc_start_training training.start_training%type,
pc_end_training training.end_training%type
)
is 
begin
 if pc_id_user = training.id_user then
  if pc_start_training between training.start_training and training.end_training then
   if pc_end_training between training.start_training and training.end_training then
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20099,'NO PUEDE REGISTRAR OTRA CHARLA SI AUN MANTIENE CHARLA VIGENTE.');
        END IF;
    END IF;
else
 insert into training(id_training,id_user,start_training,end_training)
 values(pc_id_training,pc_id_user,pc_start_training,pc_end_training);
end if;
end;
```

Comment: no me queda bien claro.... por lo que entendi, estas realizando un insert a la tabla training? y todos los insert que vienen con fecha del 01-01-18 al 05-01-18  no se aplican? eso?

Comment: si, estoy realizando un insert. En las fechas es el problema porque puedo ingresar diferentes fechas pero como dije si en el primer registro tengo el rango de 01-01 hasta 05-01 no debería permitirme hacer un insert en training entre ese rango de fechas

Comment: debieras hacer un procedimiento almacenado y condicionar el insert en  esas fechas.

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo actualizo para mostrar mi procedure, pero me sale este error: "Table,View Or Sequence reference 'training.id_training' not allowed in this context

Comment: no es un duplicado de esta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92478/324... pero estas pidiendo algo que ya vimos?

Comment: Disculpa no le veo el parecido ...