# SQL - Filtro por rango fechas con doble columna

Tags: sql, datetime, tsql

Hola tengo un problema con una consulta. Quiero filtrar por rangos de fecha con dos columnas. Inicio y Final.

```
X | Inicio    | Fin  
1 |2018-10-01 | 2018-10-31  
2 |2018-11-01 | 2018-11-30  
3 |2018-11-15 | 2018-12-15  

Inicio BETWEEN @parametroInicial AND @parametroFinal  
AND  
Fin BETWEEN @parametroInicial AND @parametroFinal
```

No me ha funcionado.
Filtros sencillos como @parametroInicial <= Inicio tampoco :(.

Los tipos de dato de las columnas y parametros son: DATETIME.

Ejemplo: en la tabla está el mes de noviembre, si envío los parámetros '2018-11-01' a '2018-11-30' me debería regresar los registros 2 y 3 y de la misma forma si envío '2018-11-14' a '2018-11-16'

El problema que he visto es que en algunos filtros se limita a todo lo que esta fuera del rango o exlusivamente dentro de el rango por lo tanto los registros que su fecha inicial no esta dentro, aunque su fecha final sí lo esté, no salen en el resultado.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7NON.jpg <- una imagen de referencia

Comment: Buen día. Estoy seguro que si funciona, y se puede hacer funcionar para muchos casos. Sin embargo, sin ver un ejemplo de las fechas que quieres dar y el resultado que esperas obtener del ejemplo de datos que has dado, no se puede decir la manera de resolverlo.

Comment: Cómo estás asignando valores a las variables?, qué motor de base de datos y versión estás usando (asumo SQL Server)?, qué tipo de datos son las columnas Inicio y Fin?

Comment: Creo que esto te puede servir: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos/92772#92772

Comment: @jachguate Ejemplo: en la tabla está el mes de noviembre, si envío los parámetros '2018-11-01' a '2018-11-30' me debería regresar los registros 2 y 3 y de la misma forma si envío '2018-11-14' a '2018-11-16'

Comment: @Roberto, por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye esa información. De esta manera quedará más completa y aumentan tus probabilidades de encontrar una repuesta.

Comment: En otras palabras, lo que buscas es cualquier intersección entre ambos rangos de fechas?

Comment: @jachguate si, algo así, como en la imagen que puse. Creo que es un sencillo problema de filtros pero no sé bien como usarlos en este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
        FROM tabla  A
        WHERE   @parametroFinal >= A.Inicio  AND
                A.Fin  >= @parametroInicial
```

Esto hará coincidir todos los rangos de fecha de la tabla y de los parámetros que tengan alguna intersección.