# Consulta que da si una fecha está en algún registro de intervalo de fechas

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla Tabla1:

```
Id: 1 ; Fecha: 2019-03-20 10:00  
Id: 2 ; Fecha: 2019-03-20 11:00  
Id: 3 ; Fecha: 2019-03-21 15:00
```

y otra tabla Tabla 2:

```
Id: 1 ; FechaInicio: 2019-03-19 09:00 ; FechaFin: 2019-03-19 10:15  
Id: 2 ; FechaInicio: 2019-03-20 09:00 ; FechaFin: 2019-03-20 10:15  
Id: 3 ; FechaInicio: 2019-03-21 09:00 ; FechaFin: 2019-03-21 10:15  
Id: 4 ; FechaInicio: 2019-03-21 14:00 ; FechaFin: 2019-03-16 10:15
```

¿Cómo hago una consulta para que me indique si los registros de la tabla1 su fecha está o no incluida en algún intervalo de la tabla2?
Algo que de un resultado como:

```
1, 2019-03-20 10:00, 1  
2, 2019-03-20 11:00, 0  
3, 2019-03-21 15:00, 1
```

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido Fernando a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos/92772#92772

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Si tu tipo de datos es datetime u otro similar, lo podrías realizar simplemente con un `LEFT JOIN` comparando rangos (`BETWEEN`).

```
DECLARE @buscar TABLE (Id int, Fecha datetime)
INSERT INTO @buscar
VALUES
    (1,'20-03-2019 10:00:00.000'),  
    (2,'20-03-2019 11:00:00.000'),  
    (3,'21-03-2019 15:00:00.000')

DECLARE @rangos TABLE (Id int, FechaInicio datetime, FechaFin datetime)

INSERT INTO @rangos
VALUES
    (1,'19-03-2019 09:00:00.000','19-03-2019 10:15:00.000'), 
    (2,'20-03-2019 09:00:00.000','20-03-2019 10:15:00.000'), 
    (3,'21-03-2019 09:00:00.000','21-03-2019 10:15:00.000'), 
    (4,'21-03-2019 14:00:00.000','16-03-2019 15:15:00.000') --> fecha inferior a la del inicio, rango NO es correcto?


SELECT 
    b.Id,
    b.Fecha,
    ISNULL(r.Id,0) AS [id_rangos]
FROM @buscar b
LEFT JOIN @rangos r
    ON b.Fecha BETWEEN r.FechaInicio AND r.FechaFin
```

Como observación el último dato de tus rangos al parecer no esta correcto.

Answer (score 0):

Yo mismo me respondo:

```
select t1.id, t1.fecha, case when t2.id is null then 0 else 1 end as DentroDeT2  
from tabla1 t1 left outer join tabla2 t2 on t1.fecha>=t2.fechaInicio and t1.fecha<t2.fechaFin  
group by t1.id, t1.fecha.
```

Lo que hago es crear una relación NO de igualdad, sino de comparación dentro del intervalo. No sabía que se podía.