# Como traer datos de una tabla que no coinciden con otra en rango de fechas

Tags: mysql

Amablemente solicito ayuda con una consulta MySQL, hace un tiempo hice una aplicación de reservación de salas y actualmente el cliente me solicitó colocar la opción de búsqueda de salas libres en determinado lapso de tiempo, es decir, ingresar dos campos para la hora inicial y la hora final y mostrar las salas que tenían disponibles ese tiempo.

Estas son mis dos tablas:

[image]

Las tablas tienen más campos de los visibles, pero estos son los que se necesitan para la consulta.

Cuando quiero saber qué reservaciones hay en un lapso de tiempo específico ("2019-04-23 12:01:00" y "2019-04-23 13:59:00" para el ejemplo) hago esta consulta:

```
SELECT reservas.id, reservas.id_sala, salas.nombre 
FROM reservas 
LEFT JOIN salas ON reservas.id_sala = salas.id 
WHERE 
((desde <= "2019-04-23 12:01:00" AND hasta >= "2019-04-23 13:59:00") 
OR desde BETWEEN "2019-04-23 12:01:00" AND "2019-04-23 13:59:00" 
OR hasta BETWEEN "2019-04-23 12:01:00" AND "2019-04-23 13:59:00")
```

(A los campos 'desde' les sumo un minuto y a los campos 'hasta' les resto uno, esto con el fin de que no devuelva una reserva que termine justo donde comienza una o que comience donde termine otra).

En teoría necesito justo lo contrario, obtener las salas que no estén ocupadas (reservadas) en ese preciso rango de tiempo.

He intentado con IS NULL, NOT IN y NOT EXISTS pero no lo he logrado

Esta consulta me trae las salas que se encuentran reservadas en el lapso de tiempo especificado:

```
SELECT salas.id, salas.nombre FROM salas 
LEFT OUTER JOIN reservas 
ON salas.id = reservas.id_sala 
WHERE 
((desde <= "2019-04-23 12:01:00" AND hasta >= "2019-04-23 13:59:00") 
OR desde BETWEEN "2019-04-23 12:01:00" AND "2019-04-23 13:59:00" 
OR hasta BETWEEN "2019-04-23 12:01:00" AND "2019-04-23 13:59:00")
```

Agradezco mucho su colaboración

Answer (score 2):

En principio, para saber que salas estarían ocupadas en el período indicado puedes hacer:

```
SELECT R.id_sala
       FROM reservas R
       WHERE R.desde <= '2019-04-23 13:59:00' AND
             R.hasta >= '2019-04-23 12:01:00'
```

Luego, podríamos negar esta consulta para saber cuales estarían libres:

```
SELECT salas.id, salas.nombre 
       FROM salas
       WHERE salas.id NOT IN ( SELECT R.id_sala
                                      FROM reservas R
                                           WHERE R.desde <= '2019-04-23 13:59:00' AND
                                                 R.hasta >= '2019-04-23 12:01:00'
                             )
```

Para una explicación más general de como funcionan las relaciones entre los intervalos de reservas y el intervalo solicitado, puedes ver: [¿Como verificar si dos intervalos de datos tienen elementos compartidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos)

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba! Enormemente agradecido.