# ¿Cómo validar si una fecha está dentro de un rango?

Tags: mysql, sql

Buen día amigos, tengo el siguiente problema; quiero saber si una fecha está dentro de un rango, tengo una fecha inicial y una final, para ello tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS registros 
FROM mi_tabla 
WHERE fecha_inicial >= '2019-07-30' AND fecha_final <= '2019-08-04'
```

El problema es que no me muestra registro, pero sí lo hay (el problema es que los registros están entre 2019-08-01 y 2019-08-04) hay alguna manera de hacer el filtro? Ya usé `BETWEEN` pero tampoco funciona.

Esta es la estructura de la tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, debería funcionar con `between`, tal vez enviaste los parámetros al revés.

Comment: El campo fecha_Final es date o DATETIME

Comment: indicanos por favor si el campo de tu tabla es `DATE` o `DATETIME` ese *pudiera* ser un detalle

Comment: Aprendiz es datatime aunque no creo que influya ya que es para filtrar dentro de un rango. He dejado la estructura de la tabla igualmente

Comment: @Venté, es cierto, el tipo datetime no debería influir, tal vez el problema es en el espacio de `COUNT (*)` que debería ser `COUNT(*)` como alguien mas comento.

Comment: @the-breaker creo que si debería influir pues entre un campo y otro la comparación no se podrá hacer pues uno tendrá una parte time que en el otro valor no existe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es consultar las filas que se encuentran justo en la intersección de dos rangos de fechas, la consulta que puedes hacer es:

```
SELECT  COUNT (*) AS registros 
        FROM mi_tabla
        WHERE '2019-08-04' >= DATE(fecha_inicial) AND
              DATE(fecha_final) >= '2019-07-30'
```

Para una explicación más general: [¿Como verificar si dos intervalos de datos tienen elementos compartidos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/como-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos)

Comment: Muchas gracias!, con esta consulta me funcionó súper.

Answer (score 1):

Trata con esto amigo el detalle es que es un tipo DateTime y los minutos y horas te estan dando los problemas

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS registros 
FROM mi_tabla 
WHERE CAST(fecha_inicial AS DATE) >= '2019-07-30' AND CAST(fecha_inicial AS DATE) <= '2019-08-04'
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas convertir en valor de la columna a tipo `DATE` por que tu tabla lo tiene como `DATETIME` es decir necesitamos discriminar la parte `TIME` de la mismas así:

Pues al momento tu consulta una vez que se ejecuta se ve de este modo:

```
WHERE '2019-06-12 14:50:00' >= '2019-07-30'
```

Lo anterior no es posible pues ambos valores tienen una estructura diferente, donde del lado derecho solo existe la parte `TIME` y del lado izquierdo una parte `TIME` que no puede ser evaluada con su contra parte.

Creo que debería verse de este modo tu consulta:

```
WHERE DATE(fecha_inicial) >= '2019-07-30' AND DATE(fecha_final) <= '2019-08-04'
```

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Función `DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)