# Select de fechas solapadas en la misma tabla

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla donde cada fila contiene un rango de fechas definido por dos campos, fechaInicio y fechaFin. La PK es IDC + IDA + FechaInicio + FechaFin

```
IDC IDA VAL Desc        Abr FechaInicio FechaFin    MesInicio MesFin
1   0   1   Mercaderías M   20140101    20201231    201401  202012
1   0   1   Mercaderías M   20160301    20210228    201603  202102
1   1   1   Mercaderías M   20140101    20201231    201401  202012
1   1   1   Mercaderías M   20160301    20210228    201603  202102
1   2   1   Mercaderías M   20140101    20201231    201401  202012
1   2   1   Mercaderías M   20160301    20210228    201603  202102
```

Necesito sacar aquellos registros en los cuales se solapen y que tengan el mismo IDC, IDA.

Por ejemplo es siguiente registro se solaparía en fechas con el primero de la tabla anterior.

```
1   0   1   Mercaderías M   20150101    20191231    201501  201912
```

No tengo experiencia con bucles por lo que estoy bastante perdido.

Gracias de antemano,

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so]; haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio y lee [ask]. Con _solaparse_, ¿te referís a un rango de fechas que esté contenido dentro de otro rango?

Comment: @padaleiana Buenas padaleiana, exactamente. Necesito saber que registros están contienen rangos de fechas contenidos en otros registros.

Comment: Explora las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92478/182188) es posible que allí esté lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes 4 posibles vías de solapamiento. Podemos hacer la consulta con todos los datos y hacer un `INNER JOIN` por los campos que son comunes (`IDC`, `IDA`) y luego poner las condiciones.

```
        Fechas a               |----------------------|
            Caso 1         |--------------|
            Caso 2                          |--------------|
            Caso 3                 |-------------|
            Caso 4       |------------------------------|

SELECT *
FROM Tabla a
INNER JOIN Tabla b on a.IDC = b.IDC and a.IDA = b.IDA
WHERE (a.FechaInicio >= b.FechaInicio AND a.FechaFin >= b.FechaFin AND a.Inicio <= b.FechaFin) --Caso 1
OR (a.FechaInicio <= b.FechaInicio AND a.FechaFin <= b.FechaFin AND a.FechaFin >= b.FechaInicio) --Caso 2
OR (a.FechaInicio >= b.FechaInicio AND a.FechaFin <= b.FechaFin) --Caso 3
OR (a.FechaInicio <= b.FechaInicio AND a.FechaFin >= b.FechaFin) -- Caso 4
```