# ¿Cómo obtener valores entre una intersección de fechas?

Tags: date

Estoy trabado en mi desarrollo de un sistema de "reservas de recursos", con una consulta que no puedo solucionar, espero puedan ayudarme, paso a comentarles:

Tengo estás tablas en mi sistema:

"Tabla Reservas"

[image: Tabla "Reservas"]

Tabla Recurso_reservas

[image: Tabla Recurso_reservas]

Tabla Recurso_reservas

Ambas tablas están relacionadas entre si mediante los campos "id" y "reserva_id",
donde en la tabla "Recurso_reservas" están los recursos reservados en el rango de fechas que se observa en la tabla "reservas", la cuestión es la siguiente:

Necesito obtener, mediante un rango de fechas ingresados por el sistema, todos los recursos "recurso_id" que están reservados en ese rango.

Se observa de las tablas que:
Los recursos con recurso_id = 1,2,3,88,104,105 están reservados desde 2021-08-23 hasta 2021-08-26
Los recursos con recurso_id = 4,5,6 están reservados desde 2021-08-25 hasta 2021-08-27

He intentado con esta consulta:

```
SELECT recurso_id FROM `recurso_reservas` a  
INNER JOIN `reservas` b ON b.`id` = a.`reserva_id`  
WHERE (fecha_desde >= '2021-08-25' AND fecha_hasta <= '2021-08-27');
```

Pero solo obtengo los recursos recurso_id = 4,5,6, pero necesitaria obtener, además, los recursos con recurso_id = 1,2,3,88,104,105 ya que si observan en las tablas, estos están reservados desde el 2021-08-23 hasta el 2021-08-26, teniendo el día 25 en común, por lo que deberían aparecer en los resultados de mi consulta.
Luego con este resultados haré un tratamiento más especifico para impedir que estos estén disponibles para reservarse.

Espero se entienda mi problema, desde ya muchas gracias por cualquier aporte.
Saludos

Comment: Creo que esto puede responder a tu pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/c%c3%b3mo-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos/92772#92772

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Gracias, me sirvió de mucha ayuda, en el base mi respuesta, cuando termine las pruebas subire la solución por si alguien le sirve.