# ¿Como puedo hacer para que NO registre dentro de un rango de fechas?

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Supongamos que el rango de alquiler es:

fecha llegada = "10/11/2021"
fecha de salida = "18/11/2021"

Si el usuario carga dentro de ese rango esta fecha:
fecha llegada = "15/11/2021"
fecha salida = "20/11/2021"

me tendría que salir en la consulta sql la fila con este rango:
fecha llegada = "10/11/2021"
fecha de salida = "18/11/2021".

Como seria la consulta?

Comment: Me parece que esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92478/c%c3%b3mo-verificar-si-dos-intervalos-de-datos-tienen-elementos-compartidos podría responder tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias por la data!!. @PatricioMoracho , me funciono! :D