# Si hora de inicio y termino tiene disponibilidad

Tags: php, date

Esta la forma de validar un horario al enviar un hora de inicio y termino este valide que si esta dentro un rango de disponibilidad durante el día.

Ejemplo si el usuario tiene 3 registros y vamos a ingresar un nuevo dato.

```
    Hora_inicio  = '10:00:00';
    Hora_termino = '13:00:00';
    /*En este caso debe reclamar que el operario tiene esos horarios ocupados*/
   //Pero si los datos son
    Hora_inicio  = '12:00:00';
    Hora_termino = '13:00:00';
    /*En este caso debería dejarme grabar sin problemas. Ya que tiene disponibilidad entre ese rango de horas */

┌───────────────┬──────────┬
│ id │ inicio   |termino   │ 
├───────────────┼──────────┼
│ 10 │ 07:00:00 │ 10:00:00 │
│ 10 │ 10:00:00 │ 12:00:00 │
│ 10 │ 14:00:00 │ 16:00:00 │
└──────────────────────────┘
```

Tengo el siguiente if ?. Pero no me funciona

```
$inicio  = '07:00:00';
$termino = '08:00:00';

while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $hora_inicio = $row['hora_inicio'];
    $hora_termino  = $row['hora_termino'];
    $esta_en_rango = $inicio <= $hora_inicio && $termino >= $hora_termino;
    $esta_en_rango_string = $esta_en_rango ? 'true' : 'false';
    echo "<br>hora_inicio  -> ".$hora_inicio." hora_termino  ->".$hora_termino."  esta_en_rango ".$esta_en_rango;

}
```

SQL Fiddle. hora_inicio y hora_termino son time()

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bd574/2

Comment: revisa tu condicion `$esta_en_rango = $inicio <= $hora_inicio && $termino >= $hora_termino;` que tiene pinta de ser erronea. por otra parte, `hora_inicio y hora_termino son time()` en SQL, pero que son en caso de PHP? llegan como cadena de caracteres?

Comment: no es [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92478/324) ?