# ¿Cómo determinar si dos rangos de fechas se solapan en Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tengo un array que me trae varios objetos con atributos como `fechaDesde` y `fechaHasta`. Tengo que verificar que no se solapen entre ellas, es decir, si tengo:

```
 fechaDesde1 = 01/06/2022
 fechaHasta1 = 31/06/2022      
 fechaDesde2 = 22/06/2022
 fechaHasta2 = 10/07/2022
```

¿Qué método podría utilizar realizar esas validaciones y devolver como repuesta si se están solapando o no?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! mira esto.. es para sql, pero es justamente lo que estas buscando... https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/92478/324

Comment: que has intentado?

Comment: lo que se me ocurrio es buscar el ultimo objeto que se haya cargado y compararlo con el que se esta por cargar. entonces comparar la fechaDesde del objeto a cargar y la fechaHasta del ultimo objeto cargado. por lo tanto ahi comparar.

Comment: Añade el código de la solución que has intentado para que puedas recibir ayuda, prueba realizando una comparación de la fecha anterior con la fecha actual.

Answer (score 2):

Dos rangos A y B se solapan si se cumple que:

```
(A.fechaInicial <= B.fechaFinal) and (B.fechaInicial <= A.fechaFinal)
```

Puedes ver una prueba detallada de este razonamiento en [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/325933/8838721), donde han colocado 36 maneras diferentes de probar esta expresión, yo lo tomaré como un hecho para responder tu pregunta.

Partiendo de esa expresión, es trivial implementarlo en java:

```java
boolean rangesOverlap(Date startA, Date endA, Date startB, Date endB) {
    return startA.getTime() <= endB.getTime() && startB.getTime() <= endA.getTime();
}
```

Alternativamente usando `LocalDate`:

```
boolean rangesOverlap(LocalDate startA, LocalDate endA, LocalDate startB, LocalDate endB) {
    return !startA.isAfter(endB) && !startB.isAfter(endA);
}
```

Nota que en este último caso, para simular el <=, he usado el negado de `isAfter`.

Te adjunto [un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar online](https://onlinegdb.com/RlSBmupMX) para hacer pruebas.